# Where does my docker container get internet from and how does it work

Tags: docker

I have just created and ran a docker container with a centos image . I was suprised to notice I can ping 1.0 or 1.1.1.1 as well as if I added a name server I can ping google etc. I can even ping my router private IP.

How does this work since my container private IP is something like 172.x.x.x while my network address in my house is 192.x.x.x. ?

Answer (score 1):

By default each container is started in its own [network namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces#Network_(net)) and connected to a `bridge` device using a virtual network interface.

Within its own network namespace the container also has its own routing table: if you're container e.g. has IP address `172.12.0.2/16` it usually then has `172.12.0.1` as its default gateway and that IP is assigned to the `bridge` device on the host, i.e., the host is part of multiple networks (virtual networks setup by `docker` and your physical home network) and acts as a router for the containers.

For this to work properly [IP forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/what-is-kernel-ip-forwarding) needs to be enabled, firewall/`iptables` rules to be setup correctly and in most cases the private IP addresses of the containers need to be [masqueraded](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/what-ip-masquerading-and-when-it-use/). `docker` already takes care of all of this for you in its default configuration.

For more see the [`docker` networking documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/) and especially the [`bridge` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/).